# How to remove jaggies?

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-shapes, radial-gradients

My code - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/5dLc0fzp/1/)

```css
body{
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
div{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;   
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, transparent 28px, tomato 28px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

How to remove jaggies?

[image]

Thank you, I will be glad to any help!

Comment: img { 
    image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             /* STOP SMOOTHING, GIVE ME SPEED  */
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* Firefox                        */
    image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            /* Opera                          */
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Chrome (and eventually Safari) */
    image-rendering: pixelated; /* Chrome */
    image-rendering: optimize-contrast;         /* CSS3 Proposed                  */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   /* IE8+                           */

}

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar `crispEdges` is for SVG but would probably defeat what the questioner is trying to do anyway. Also true for the other properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a different approach with a large `box-shadow` on a round element:

```css
body {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.bitten {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}

.bitten::before {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px tomato;
  content: '';
  height: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 28px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bitten"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers, you can prevent jaggies by not having sharp edges to your gradient. So rather than `transparent 28px, tomato 28px`, you make the transition between the colors a bit smoother, say by 1px.

```css
body{
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
div{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;   
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, rgba(255,99,71,0) 28px, rgba(255,99,71,255) 30px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

But this doesn't work everywhere. For a more solid approach, see the other answer.

Comment: Chrome somehow manages to make this look jagged no matter how many pixels are between the two…

Comment: Hm, I don't know why I always assume Chrome is as good as my own browser. Thanks for the warning!

Comment: Yeah, I actually expected it to work, and now I have to go rewrite a few of my pages that use this approach :( [Zoomed-in Chrome messing this up at 6px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxcP4.png)